# Postgres wrong query result with timezones

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, timezone, postgresql-9.4

My Table looks like this:

Inventory

```
inventory | creationDate
{}        | 2017-04-27 14:15:15.25+02
{}        | 2017-04-27 13:03:02.205+02
{}        | 2017-04-27 13:03:01.766+02
{}        | 2017-04-27 13:02:19.8+02
{}        | 2017-04-27 12:35:52.12+02
```

The Query:

```
SELECT * FROM "Inventory" 
WHERE "registerTillInventoryId" = 1 
AND "creationDate" <= '2017-04-27 12:02:38.000 +00:00' 
ORDER BY "creationDate" DESC;
```

The Result:

```
inventory | creationDate
{}        | 2017-04-27 13:03:02.205+02
{}        | 2017-04-27 13:03:01.766+02
{}        | 2017-04-27 13:02:19.8+02
{}        | 2017-04-27 12:35:52.12+02
```

My question is why i get the data from

```
13:03:02.205+02 and 13:03:01.766+02
```

The result of my query should be

```
inventory | creationDate
{}        | 2017-04-27 13:02:19.8+02
{}        | 2017-04-27 12:35:52.12+02
```

Comment: if i dont use DESC i get the result in a wrong order

Comment: The Result is wrong i get data after 12:02:38.000

Comment: @OtoShavadze why? `'2017-04-27 12:02:38.000 +00:00'` is `'2017-04-27 14:02:38.000 +00:02'`, no? :)

Comment: '2017-04-27 12:02:38.000 +00:00' < 2017-04-27 13:03:02.205+02

Comment: `'2017-04-27 12:02:38.000 +00:00'` is `'2017-04-27 14:02:38.000 +00:02'` and  `'2017-04-27 14:02:38.000 +00:02'` > `2017-04-27 13:03:02.205+02`

Comment: why not just `"creationDate" <= '2017-04-27 12:02:38.000' `?.. you wont get the result you desired of course. I'm asking why do you mix tz in first place?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay thank you for the Help. I fiqured out the problem with the help of the Comment of Vao Tsun.

What i didn't descriped was that i tried to get 13:02 from 12:02 +00:00

I do not really need the Timezones.
So if I query

```
creationDate < '2017-04-27 13:02:38.000'
```

directly. Without Timezones i get my right result.

```
{} | 2017-04-27 13:02:19.8+02
{} | 2017-04-27 12:35:52.12+02
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`'2017-04-27 12:02:38.000 +00:00'` is `'2017-04-27 14:02:38.000 +00:02'`,
so it returns all but `'2017-04-27 14:15:15.25+02'` as it the only value that does not comply `"creationDate" <= '2017-04-27 12:02:38.000 +00:00'`

which is right. example:

```
t=# with a as (select '2017-04-27 12:02:38.000 +00:00' at time zone 'utc' ts)
select ts, ts at time zone 'gmt+2' from a;
         ts          |        timezone
---------------------+------------------------
 2017-04-27 12:02:38 | 2017-04-27 14:02:38+00
(1 row)

Time: 0.480 ms
```

why not just `"creationDate" <= '2017-04-27 12:02:38.000'` to avoid mixing tz?..